# How to access the Orders properties from the Customer instance?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have two tables as part of my learning c# and asp.net. Customer and Orders and its a 1:m relationship in my POCO.

```
public class Customer
{
public int CustID {get; set;}
public string FirstName {get; set;}
public string LastName {get; set;}
public List<Orders> orders {get; set;}
}

public class Orders
{
public int OrdersID {get; set;}
public int CustID {get; set;}
public string OrderName {get; set;}
public virtual Customer customer {get; set;}
}
```

Now my question is how do show a list of both Customer and orders in one view from the Customer instance **not** Orders instance.

This is what I have in my controller:

```
    namespace MvcApplication3.Controllers
{ 
    public class janController : Controller
    {
        private coContext db = new coContext();

     public ViewResult Index()
        {

        return View(db.customer.ToList());
    }
```

Code for my DbContext:

```
    namespace MvcApplication3.Models
{
    public class coContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Customer> customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Orders> orders { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My partial view has the code below:

```
 @model List<MvcApplication3.Models.Customer>
 @foreach(var customer in Model) {
    <div>Display customer props:</div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => customer.LastName)

    <div>Display Orders:
        **@foreach(var order in customer.Orders)** {
            <div>Display some order props:
              @Html.DisplayFor(m => order.OrderName)
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

I intend to view the child properties or data from my customer insatnce. In brief I want to read related data based on customer i.e customer FirstName Lastname (these must be unique) then have the related data after that (OrderName). Thats what I am trying to do.

Comment: Is your question about retrieving the orders from the database? Or is the question about displaying a child collection in a view?

Comment: @Jan Thank Jan. Its about displaying a child collection in a view.

Comment: So you should show what your view looks like so far

Comment: @jan My view from the customer instance show Customer properties. However I am looking at a way to show or read related data from the customer instance. I can do that from the Orders instance using **db.orders.include(c=>c.customer).ToList()** and having this in my view  **@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.customer.LastName)**.

Comment: Something you may be forgetting about is the fact of using lazy loading or not..... depending if you are using EF4.X/5.X CodeFirst or not, you my need to do something like: var res = db.Customers.where(x=>x.Deleted != null).include(x=>x.Orders).toList(); Otherwise (if you do not load all the "child" properties" you will not be able to show then in the view).

Comment: @emanyalpsid Thanks Emanyalpsid. How to I load the child properties in my view. I tried this **Html.DisplayFo(modelItem =>item.orders.OrderName** but it work let me do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure, whats exactly your question, but i try to answer it.
From your comments i read, you want to know, how to display related data in a view.

```
@model List<Customer>

@foreach(var customer in Model) {
    <div>Display customer props:</div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => customer.LastName)

    <div>Display Orders:
        @foreach(var order in customer.Orders) {
            <div>Display some order props:
              @Html.DisplayFor(m => order.OrderName)
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

**EDIT**

I have took a look at your project. You have this code in your view:

```
@foreach(var customer in Model) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => customer.LastName)
}

@foreach(var order in customer.orders) {
    <div>Display some order props:
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => order.OrderName)
    </div>
}
```

The problem is, that you are closing the first foreach loop where you have to embed the second one inside the first one. Thats the reason the variable `customer` is not known in your second loop. It has to be like this:

```
@foreach(var customer in Model) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => customer.LastName)

    @foreach(var order in customer.orders) {
        <div>Display some order props:
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => order.OrderName)
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a problem here  **@foreach(var order in customer.Orders)**. I  have posted my project [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=F6CEA54D10B37C92!117).

Comment: **What** for a problem you have?

Comment: It says the name customer does not exist in the current context.

Comment: in my example `customer` is the loop variable: `@foreach(var customer in Model) {` you have to show your code.

Comment: Please check this [link](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=F6CEA54D10B37C92!117) of all my code. I  can not post it on my comments.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to write my "comments" all together as an answer:

http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/

**1 -** Something you may be forgetting about is the fact of using lazy loading or not..... depending if you are using EF4.X/5.X CodeFirst or not, you may need to do something like:

```
var res = db.Customers.where(x=>x.Deleted != null).include(x=>x.Orders).toList();
```

Otherwise (if you do not load all the "child" properties" you will not be able to show then in the view)

**2-** Sithelo > @emanyalpsid Thanks Emanyalpsid. How to I load the child properties in my view. I tried this Html.DisplayFo(modelItem =>item.orders.OrderName but it work let me do that.

You can use different ways, such as the Jan solution, or something else like: MVC editortemplates: http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/

Comment: Thanks for the post and link. I notice the that the person address are already hard coded. Mine isnt. I have to retrieve from a database and the orders class has foreign key to associate with the customer class. Still I need to know how I can view Person and address all in one view as the example you gave me but retrieving the data from a database.

Comment: Could you please tell us more about the code you have and what is missing? Because at this point I am a little bit lost on your question.....

Comment: I have edited the question please check my sample code from this [link](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=F6CEA54D10B37C92!117).

Comment: Thanks for that link. Please can you help. How do you avoid hard coding the data? Say my address are all in the database.